# how to prevent any paticular control to reload whenever there is a server side event occuring?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I am using dropdownlist in my asp page.
I am using server side method on change as.....

```
<asp:DropDownList id="D1" runat="server" AutoPastBack="true" onSelectedIndexChanged="cbox_server_selectedIndexChanged">
</asp>
<div id="video player"></div>
```

I am also using a div where a video is running and whenever user selecting an item from the list the page is reloaded and the video is stopped.
Javascript should get reload.
Just only the div where vedio is running should not reload.

Comment: A quick and dirty solution would be to wrap your DDL in an `UpdatePanel`. A better solution would be to use ajax and a web service.

Comment: I am a beginner and i don't know about it... Can you please provide me an example? @BenRobinson